# Removing list underline with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, underline

So I'm using Wordpress to make my website (www.codedgames.com) and the theme I'm using puts an underline on one of its lists but not the rest. I'd like to remove the underlines from the "Recent blog posts" widget of the footer with CSS. I'm not amazing at CSS or HTML so I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the HTML associated with the list:

```
    <div id="footer_two" class="span4">

<aside id="recent-posts-3" class="widget widget_recent_entries">        
<h3 class="widget-title">Recent Blog Posts</h3>     <ul>
                    <li class="">
                <a href="http://codedgames.com/moto-360-on-iphone-review/">Moto 360 on iPhone Review</a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="">
                <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-good-is-tgt/">How Good is TGT?</a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="">
                <a href="http://codedgames.com/dr-boom-used-to-suck-theory/">Dr. Boom Used to Suck – Card Theory</a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="">
                <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-to-become-a-rocket-league-pro/">How to Become a Rocket League Pro!</a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="">
                <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-to-start-a-twitch-channel/">How to Start a Twitch Channel in 6 Minutes!</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </aside>        
                                                                                                     </div>
```

Comment: If the theme is what's adding the underlines to the list, the relevant CSS from the theme would be helpful to post too. Unless you're just talking about the default underlines under hyperlinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.widget_recent_entries li {
   border-bottom: none !mportant;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration: none;` on the right element should do it...

Comment: If the OP is asking the question is likely because they don't know much about CSS or HTML - your answer (while obvious to you and me) makes little sense to the ones still learning - I suggest improving your answer (adding an explanation of where, how to include your snippet) and, thus, making the site better for everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `text-decoration: none;` in your anchor `<a>` elements.

First you will have to target your container which is `#recent-posts-3` then all the anchors inside of it.

So your selector would be:

```
#recent-posts-3 a
```

I doubt you will have specificity problems since you are using an id.

---

> **Note:** I strongly suggest that you add some styling or change on hover to 
>   let your users know there is a link there. You can see this alternative in the second demo.

---

**CODE SNIPPET [1]:**

```css
#recent-posts-3 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer_two" class="span4">

  <aside id="recent-posts-3" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
    <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Blog Posts</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/moto-360-on-iphone-review/">Moto 360 on iPhone Review</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-good-is-tgt/">How Good is TGT?</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/dr-boom-used-to-suck-theory/">Dr. Boom Used to Suck – Card Theory</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-to-become-a-rocket-league-pro/">How to Become a Rocket League Pro!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-to-start-a-twitch-channel/">How to Start a Twitch Channel in 6 Minutes!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
```

---

**CODE SNIPPET [2]**

```css
#recent-posts-3 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted currentColor;
}
#recent-posts-3 a:hover {
  background-color: gold;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer_two" class="span4">

  <aside id="recent-posts-3" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
    <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Blog Posts</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/moto-360-on-iphone-review/">Moto 360 on iPhone Review</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-good-is-tgt/">How Good is TGT?</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/dr-boom-used-to-suck-theory/">Dr. Boom Used to Suck – Card Theory</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-to-become-a-rocket-league-pro/">How to Become a Rocket League Pro!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://codedgames.com/how-to-start-a-twitch-channel/">How to Start a Twitch Channel in 6 Minutes!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
```